# Highly-available relay node (round robin & Ouroboros)

Tags: ouroboros, spo, topology

I'm thinking of adding multiple relay-node instances behind a load-balancer to avoid downtime during maintenance windows, updates, restarts, etc.

From the outside world (public network), this would be seen as a single relay (single IP address / single DNS record), but internally, each instance would be an independent node, performing its own sync procedure. There's a chance for these instances to be slightly out of sync between each other (eg: after a restart of one).

My question: is there any problem from the protocol perspective (Ouroboros, topology updater, etc) with having multiple round robin nodes answering as the same relay?

Comment: Do you have more details on how you plan on handling your topology inside the network?

Comment: This would be a cloud setup. Each relay-node instance would be connected to two subnets (1 public, 1 private). A single BP node would be running in the private subnet. Relay instances would point their topology config to the BP node + other peer relays downloaded from api.clio.one (cron job). The BP node would have a static topology file pointing only to the relay instances through the private subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No there is not any technical limitations from the protocol or topology updater preventing you from doing this.

**Considerations:** Starting external and working in, we need to consider the DNS vs Public IP side of this. In my opinion a Public IP should be avoided because if it changes, you have to resubmit your stake-pool registration.

Excluding a public IP, we are left with DNS. There are 2 main ways you can setup the DNS: just an A Record or an [SRV Record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/srv-record/). It is worth noting that the SRV record doesn't know if a network is down/a-server-is-down, so it will not replace your load balancer for those type of services.

Either decision, the next step is your load balancer(s). I haven't actually set one of up for this use case but my initial thought would be this is where you run the topology-updater script. As well as, you know, balance the load. For the topology updater, make your valency equal to the number of relays you have (*if using DNS, otherwise this won't work*). Doing this allows more than one connection per peer. This is important because you are using a load balancer which could *potentially* create a situation where there are no incoming peers to a relay. You will still want to run a topology pull script to set your relay nodes' topology.

I hope this helps!

[image: Example of Load Balancer Diagram]